# Can doxygen document java default no-arg constructors?

Tags: java, doxygen

Can doxygen be configured to infer default no-arg constructors?

i.e. in java, a `public` class without a constructor gets a default `public` no-arg constructor.

It would be nice if doxygen automatically documented such constructors...

Comment: Doxygen does not automagically  place texts with e.g. constructors etc. or create constructors etc. When this is java standard please create an enhancement request in the doxygen issue tracker including a reference to the java standard where the behavior is described.

Comment: @albert Yes it's a standard part of java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9), I believe since java 1.0. (yes: it's in the [first ed JLS](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/8.doc.html#16823)). It has no arguments, and the same access visibility as its class. Unfortunately I can't add issues (MS bought github and wants my email to use my account).